# Intercept intent to open text messaging?

Tags: android, text, android-intent

Suppose a user opens up the default messaging application, scrolls through their text message inbox, and then clicks on a specific person to open up the text messages between them. Is it possible to intercept and act upon the intent fired when they click on that person's name?

To clarify, I don't want to stop other applications from receiving the intent. I suppose intercept was a misleading word. I just want to know if there is some way to detect that the text messaging screen is being opened as well as who it is to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly believe no. Such capability would pose quite a security risk as "developers" with mischievous intentions could secretly have their app intercepting intents all throughout the device. I would suspect you have to create your own messaging app to accommodate what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're putting to much significance on `Intents.`  That is actually just an action internal to the application.  Not everything you click in Android results in an `Intent` being fired and even if it does, not all intents are broadcast to everybody.  In this case, what happens is you touch a list and it opens up another activity, likely via `startActivity` (which does make use of an `Intent` but not a broadcast).  Additionally, it's not possible to "intercept" `Intents.`  You can act on them, sure, but you can't prevent other applications from seeing them if they are broadcast.